# How to return data from more than one controller to a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

This has got to be a common situation, maybe I'm just searching on the wrong terms...

I have an ASP.NET MVC project using EF Code First.

I have one Object/Table/Controller for EmailTypes (e.g. Home, Work, School). The object is simple, just an ID and a Name field. This makes it easy to manage the various email types.

I have another Object/Table/Controller for Emails. It has an ID, Name (e.g. bob@me.com) and EmailType property.

In my View to create a new Email, I have a textbox to enter the email address.
I also need to put a dropdown there so that an EmailType can be chosen and assigned to the email. This is pretty standard stuff I think.

So... in my EmailController, the **Create()** function returns only a View().

**I need to also return data to populate the EmailType dropdown.**

How do I accomplish this?

(Note: I suppose I could use JQuery/AJAX to pull this data in, I could also maybe stuff it into a ViewBag or something like that, but it seems like there should be a more direct way?)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience it is futile to strictly set up one controller per entity. That is, controller actions can and should be able to work with more than one type of entity. I think the best option in this case is to abstract the code for retrieving the list of EmailTypes into a service class, and then call it from both the`EmailController.Create()` and `EmailTypesController.Index()`.

Then, you can add the property `IList<SelectListItem> EmailTypes { get; set; }` to a ViewModel for the `EmailController.Create()` action's view.